# J-Query tabs not working in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

I seem to be having some problems with my J-Query when using Woocommerce. I have installed Woocommerce and am using a custom theme (Foundation-master). Woocommerce works fine apart from  the J-query of certain elements. For example on the checkout page the "ship to different address form" is always displayed despite whether the checkbox is ticked and when clicking on different payment options the default option is always displayed.

There are no conflicts in the console.

When I switch to the Twenty Fourteen theme Woocommerce works fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or would anyone be able to point me in the direction of a way to get closer to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue of how i was registering my scripts. See here 
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2284-foundation-5-to-wordpress-js-jquery-scripts