# Woocommerce / Jigoshop tabs not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jigoshop

I'm having a problem with my own Wordpress theme which doesn't seem to be loading jQuery properly. Namely I've tried both WooCommerce and JigoShop and on the product pages the tabs are not loading properly (panels both displaying).

```
http://109.73.175.5/~maktest/product/test-product/
```

I don't see any errors in the console so not sure what it could be. At first I thought maybe it's to do with the CSS https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2739

But jQuery conflict seems to be culprit unfortunately I can't seem to correct it.

I had a look here [J-Query tabs not working in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487504/j-query-tabs-not-working-in-woocommerce) and http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2284-foundation-5-to-wordpress-js-jquery-scripts

My functions.php file therefore looks like

```
function register_my_scripts() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');  
wp_register_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js", array(),'2.1.0',false);
wp_register_script( 'google-jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('google-jquery-ui');
}

function register_my_styles(){
wp_enqueue_style( 'geeniehair-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts','register_my_scripts');
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'register_my_styles');
```

This hasn't fixed my problem either. Also I don't know if it's a good idea to de-register the core bundled version of jQuery.

I'm stuck on this so hope someone can have a look and at least point out the blaring obvious if that's what it is.

Comment: Both jQuery and jQueryUI can be loaded from WordPress core, so I'd suggest leaving those in place. The WooCommerce tabs script is loaded via `single-product.js` and doesn't appear to be jQueryUI driven. The tabs work by default though, so if they aren't it must be something in your theme... which is impossible to say from the code you've posted and because I don't know anything about JigoShop which is currently running on your live site. Try switching to a default theme to confirm.

Comment: If I go to the admin page I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Also I've activated WooCommerce.

Comment: The admin is different from the front end you originally posted about. First, get rid of the google scripts. Second, note *where* the error is coming from. I reloaded your page and noticed that the `single-product.js` script is *not* loaded, nor is any other script being loaded in the footer. Are you using `wp_footer()` in your theme? If not, you absolutely need to be.

Comment: Wonderful! The issue in this instance was not calling wp_footer() which I know should always be there! I see now I should have looked more closely at what scripts were being loaded in header / footer to determine if they were being loaded in the first place. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer to close the question:

I reloaded your page and noticed that the `single-product.js` script is not loaded, nor is any other script being loaded in the footer. Are you using `wp_footer()` in your theme? If not, you absolutely need to be.